# Synchronous GET requests in angular2

Tags: api, http, angular, get, synchronous

I want to make a component in Angular2 where in a loop of 50 iterations will execute and I want to send GET requests only in the even iterations. Now I want to send **synchronous GET requests** such that unless and until data from the even iteration is not received, the loop should wait and not enter the odd iteration. Any ideas on how that can be done?

Here's the function written in the service - `

```
     getUser() {
     for(let i = 1;i < 10;i++) {
      if (i % 2 != 0) {         
      var resp =this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+i)
          .map(res=> res.json());

      if(resp){
      resp.subscribe(res=>{
        console.log(res);
      });
    }

  }
  else{
    console.log("even iteration");
  }
}
```

Here's the output-
[image: And here's the output -]

I hope the problem is clear now.The responses should come in order and the even iteration console message should be displayed only when its odd counterpart has returned the object. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Sync requests is one of the worst things you can do in a web application and Angular itself doesn't provide any support. You can of course use the normal JS way as well to do that if you think you must.

Comment: The situation requires me to do so. Is there no way this can be achieved in angular2 ?

Comment: That's not related to Angular2. Just search how to do it in JavaScript, then do the same in Angular. And no, there is no situation that requires you to do so. There are sane ways, but you would need to provide more information about the problem that you actually try to solve.

Comment: So if i work on the above problem by making async requests instead of synchronous ones , will it give me the same results ? Sorry I am a beginner so i dont know much.

Comment: You would probably write your code differently but it's possible. but I don't know what the problem is that you try to solve. Please share the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: haven't written any yet.My instructor has asked me to solve this problem

Comment: Sir, is the flatMap operator of any use here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the help of my instructor, we finally achieved what we wanted.We sent asynchronous requests and returned the responses as observables .Now we concatented these observables,returned on alternated loop iterations and achieved the following output-   [image: output]

This is my code-

service.ts -

```
getUser(i: number): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + i)
    .map(res => res.json());

 }
```

component.ts -

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AppService} from "./app.service";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html'
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  name:string;
  call: Observable<any>;

   constructor(private _service: AppService) {}

    public ngOnInit() {

   }

  getUser(){
    this.call = Observable.concat();
   for(let i=1;i<=10;i++) {
     if(i%2!=0){
       this.call = this.call.concat(this._service.getUser(i));
      }
     else{
       this.call = this.call.concat(Observable.create(x=> {x.next(i)}).first());
      }
    }
        this.call.subscribe(res=>console.log(res));

    }
  }
```